# Why aren't badges removed?

Tags: support, feature-request, badges

Why aren't badges removed in some cases?
For example,when I downvote a question and remove the downvote I get the [image] badge.

Comment: It's an achievement. They mean that *you've come forward to put your downvote* (at least once in your SE life), when no others had the courage  :D

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: that should be an answer.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS: Well, it's just a suggestion of mine. What if it meant something else? Usually, I don't answer on vague grounds ;-)

Comment: this is not a bug.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why doesn't undo-ing your 1st down vote take away Critic badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165610/why-doesnt-undo-ing-your-1st-down-vote-take-away-critic-badge), itself a duplicate of [How do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) at MSO.

Answer (score 3):

A badge is a reward for taking the time and effort to make the site better. Removing a downvote does not negate the effort you've put in, so you still deserve the badge.